# Are amazon s3 folders browsable?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a little cloud api based on amazon which uploads a file with a 20 chars random title.
This file is public, but can anyone access it without knowing the filename?

*Example*: **`amazonurl.com/mybucket/myfolder/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt`**

Can someone browse mybucket or myfolder and access the file anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, S3 does not autogenerate an index.html as some webservers do. You need to explicitly define the file you are referencing to access it.

Comment: thanks, so I guess that's secure(ish).